# Give a reference to another project/winform in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on [SignalR For Winforms](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b) official example. The way they handle UI interaction is using the `Program` instance/reference as you can see in the code below:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //here they used Program....
        Program.MainForm.WriteToConsole("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool graceFull)
    {
        Program.MainForm.WriteToConsole("Client disconnected: " + Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(graceFull);
    }
}
```

My question is, I have created an empty solution in Visual Studio and I added 2 projects, one is a WinForms project, The other is a class library.

Obviously I can not give a `Program` reference from WinForms project in the `MyHub` class which is in the class library project since as far as I know the `Hub` or `MyHub` class should not be instantiated...its just there for the sake of Reflection.

Is there a way that I can pass a reference to my winforms to the `MyHub` class either statically or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just solved by adding a static field (an interface which is implemented by the `Form`:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static ICommunicationOwner Owner;

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Owner.GetData("Client connected: ", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool graceFull)
    {
        Owner.GetData("Client disconnected: ", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(graceFull);
    }
}
```

In the server class I did like this:

```
    public void StartServer()
    {
        MyHub.Owner = _owner;
        try
        {
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(_serverUri);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException e)
        {
            _isServerStarted = false;
            _owner.GetData("Connection", "Error starting server: " + e.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _isServerStarted = false;
            _owner.GetData("Connection", "Error starting server: " + e.Message);
            return;
        }

        _owner.GetData("Connection", "Successful");
        _isServerStarted = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively my strongly recommendation is use SignalR Self-Host.This mechanism is very helpful for you. This is a step by step tutorial:

[Self-Host](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

This mechanism work like this: You are creating a signalr host which is like push data to specific port. This host can be console application,asp.net mvc application or winform etc. Then other project or class library will be client (Signalr has packages as 'SignalR Javascript Client' and 'SignalR .NET Client')
. Web application will take a message as a javascript client, other application such as winforms or console will take a message as .net client. This mechanism is a really scalable and extendable.